# Scrolling BG missing after coming back from being suspended (iOS-SpriteKit-iphone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I have an issue with my scrolling Background (WAVE) for a game I'm developing in Objective C Sprite Kit framework.  I'm using a method from the book 'iOS Games by tutorials' (highly recommended- very informative book) as a guideline, as I'm new to it.

I got everything to work fine, but after I close the game.. and my iPhone been sitting for right around 20-30 minutes - I come back to the game and the Scrolling BG is blank for 5-15 seconds then it loads and scrolls.  Oddly, when I first test the game - it loads immediately no issues.  I also have nodes / graphics and they all load quickly each and every time no issues.

Here's the main code snippet that's being updated every frame:

```
- (void)moveWave
{

    CGPoint waveVelocity = CGPointMake(-wave_speed, 0);
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(waveVelocity, _dt);
    _waveLayer.position = CGPointAdd(_waveLayer.position, amtToMove);

    [_waveLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"wave"
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
                                   SKSpriteNode * wave = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
                                   CGPoint waveScreenPos = [_waveLayer convertPoint:wave.position
                                                                         toNode:self];
                                   if (waveScreenPos.x <= -wave.size.width) {
                                       wave.position = CGPointMake(wave.position.x+wave.size.width*2,
                                                                 wave.position.y);
                                   }
                               }];

}
```

---

Any help or insight to why coming back to the iPhone being idle for 20 minutes then load the game back up, only the scrolling BG is missing but after 5-15 seconds , it starts and looks fine.  Again, when I first load it.. or exit out for 5 minutes then go back into game.. everything is working and loads immediately.

EDIT - I know it's the scrolling function/method because I have tried just loading the BG image without scrolling and it loads fine even after I have quit the game for 20+ minutes and come back.  hmmmm.. I can play the game even when the scrolling BG isn't loaded.  The scrolling BG always loads eventually - usually 5-10 seconds later.

Comment: While iOS is preparing to move your app to the foreground (after being in the background for a while), it displays your app's launch image. If your app doesn't have a launch image, the screen will be blank.

Comment: Thanks code monkey, appreciate you trying to help - but that's not the issue, the screen isn't blank.. the game loads and all assets are there except the scrolling background.  Then after 5-10 seconds (once the game has already loaded) the scrolling BG loads.

Comment: Do you pause the game prior changing to background mode?

Comment: I don't have any pause functions.  So basically the game works as expected when I first test on iPhone. I have multiple nodes / layers , scrolling bg, etc...  When I exit game for 5-10 minutes, come back.. everything gets loaded fine / immediately - as expected.  When it's 20+ minutes, everything loads fine EXCEPT the scrolling BG layer.  But after about 10 seconds , it loads and all is working as expected.  I'm pretty puzzled, I appreciate your input!  At this point in testing, it's a small game.. with maybe 15 assets total so I'm not sure it's an Atlas/texture management issue either.

Comment: Try pausing the game before entering background mode and then un-pause when your app becomes active.

Comment: Ok I'm a newbie, sorry… what's how to detect when App goes into background mode?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely the delta time.

Well I found the best temp / workaround solution.

It's limiting the _dt …

```
if (_dt > 1) {
        _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;

    }
```

This has been working great for my purpose as _dt shouldn't really ever reach above 1 in real scenarios- there's a more in-depth approach that you store the value when the game exits, resumes.. but this is simplest imo.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to 1) pause the game when the user presses the home button and 2) resume the game when the user taps on the app's icon.

```
    // Register to be notified when the app is about to change to background state
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:app];
```

This method is called prior to the app entering background mode.

```
- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Pause the game
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    // Register to be notified when app is about to become the foreground app
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForegroundOrDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:app];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                                  object:app];
}
```

This method is called prior to the app entering foreground mode.

```
- (void) applicationWillEnterForegroundOrDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                                  object:app];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:app];
    // Add tap recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

This method resumes the game when user taps the screen.

```
- (void) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // Remove the tap recognizer
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    // Resume the game
    self.scene.view.paused = NO;
}
```

Comment: Well at first I thought it fixed the issue but it did not..first time I waited 30 minutes before re-launching the game and it worked.. after 45 minutes and yet again the scrolling BG isn't there.  I can play game and all other nodes are there and play as expected, then 5-10 seconds the scrolling BG is there.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: The image is 320x480, someone else mentioned it could be possibly the Delta time.. this is what they said 'The time difference is probably very large and throwing off your math. You may need to store the time when you exit the game and then use that to find the time offset when loading the app again.' This is all relatively new but will see what I can figure out.

Comment: Where are you calculating delta time? If it's in the game's update method, it will not be updated when you pause the SKView.